# VueJS - Display Countdown of setInterval function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, timer, setinterval

I have a function being triggered within mounted, and then it gets called every 15 minutes after that. In my component I want to display a countdown until the next setInterval in minutes/seconds.

```
 async mounted() {
  this.pullData();
  setInterval(function(){this.pullData(); }, 900000);  
},
```

```
async pullData() {
   this.loading = true;
   const getData = await axios.get(`/api/v1/card/${this.card}`);
   this.data = await getData.data.data;
   this.loading = false;
}
```

How am I able to repeatedly countdown the time until the next setInterval runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `pullData` function create new `interval` and add `leftTime = 900000`  field which will updating every second :

```js
async pullData() {
   setInterval(() => {
     this.leftTime = -= 1000;
     console.log(leftTime)
   }, 1000);
   this.loading = true;
   const getData = await axios.get(`/api/v1/card/${this.card}`);
   this.data = await getData.data.data;
   this.loading = false;
}
```